# See if an Array includes Values from 2 Other or more Array

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to see if the current list of selected values are included in 2 or more array that I have setup;

My Check gets Completely Bypassed and Never Equates to True

```
    tempDaysArray = ["13", "14", "15" ,"16" , "17" , "18" , "19" , "20", "21", "22","23","24","25","26"]; // just an example but its more or less how the values would look 

    var xmasPhase1: string[];
    var xmasPhase2: string[];
    var xmasPhase3: string[];

    xmasPhase1 = ["15" , "16" , "17" , "18" , "19" , "20"];
    xmasPhase2 = ["21" , "22" , "23" , "24" , "25" , "26"];
    xmasPhase3 = ["27" , "28" , "29" , "30" , "31"];

  const multiPhase = tempDaysArray.some(r=> xmasPhase1.includes(r) && xmasPhase2.includes(r) || xmasPhase3.includes(r) && xmasPhase2.includes(r) || xmasPhase1.includes(r) && xmasPhase3.includes(r))

  if(multiPhase){
    //Do Something 
  }
```

I know thats an extremely Ugly approach but its the closest ive come to something concrete and im clean out of ideas

Im aware of a few ways to Compare an Array to an Array The issue is finding similarity in 2 arrays. having X have a Similarity in Y & Z to do something

Comment: `xmasPhase1.includes(r) && xmasPhase2.includes(r)` will never be `true`, because there is not a single value that is in both arrays. You probably wanted to do some other logic, or you wanted to have different values in those arrays. Same goes for other checks that you do after the first.

Comment: `[xmasPhase1, xmasPhase2, xmasPhase3].filter(...).length >= 2`

Comment: @Ma3x Ah So the Values would have to be in Both Array then, So both would need E.G "15" Those Values are Correct my Logic would have to change and I guess somewhat the pretence of the question. How do I then Compare to see if it has a Value from 1 and 2 or more

Comment: @Andreas are u referring to something like this? :

```const MultiPhase2 = [xmasPhase1, xmasPhase2, xmasPhase3].filter(o1 => tempDaysArray.some(o2 => o1 === o2));
``` 
My Syntax is a bit off but not to sure what the spread op is intended for

Comment: _"My Syntax is a bit off but not to sure what the spread op is intended for"_ - It's just a placeholder for the missing check. Otherwise it would have been an answer ;) Why `.some()`? Shouldn't that be an `.every()`?

Comment: You are very Correct @Andreas that should 100% be a Every() I resolved the issue u got me thinking a bit with that placeholder its scruffy I wouldnt mind if someone gives me a better approach ill post as asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on additional information from the comments, I am assuming you want to know if values from the `tempDaysArray` intersect (fall into) with more than just one of the three `xmasPhase` arrays.

Then you would change the logic, to check which of the `xmasPhase` arrays include at least one of the values from the `tempDaysArray`. So you would iterate over all `xmasPhase` arrays and do the check.
After you do that, then a multiPhase is just a result that is longer than 1.

Feel free to correct me in the comments if my assumptions are wrong, and I can try to adjust the logic.

```js
// just an example but its more or less how the values would look 
tempDaysArray = ["13", "14", "15" ,"16" , "17" , "18" , "19" , "20", "21", "22","23","24","25","26"]; 


xmasPhase1 = ["15" , "16" , "17" , "18" , "19" , "20"];
xmasPhase2 = ["21" , "22" , "23" , "24" , "25" , "26"];
xmasPhase3 = ["27" , "28" , "29" , "30" , "31"];


activePhases = [xmasPhase1, xmasPhase2, xmasPhase3].filter(phase =>
  phase.some(day => tempDaysArray.includes(day))
)

multiPhase = activePhases.length > 1

if(multiPhase){
  //Do Something
  console.log('tempDaysArray is a multi phase') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Very much Appreciate an Improvement on this solution if possible, Its Extremely Scruffy but this resolves  the question for me:

```
 const multiPhase3 = tempDaysArray.some(r=> xmasPhase1.includes(r));
 const MultiPhase2 = tempDaysArray.some(r=> xmasPhase2.includes(r));
 const multiPhase = tempDaysArray.every(r=> xmasPhase3.includes(r));
   
 if(multiPhase && MultiPhase2 || MultiPhase2 && multiPhase3 || multiPhase && multiPhase3){
     this.errorType = 'decMultiPhaseError';
     this.banperiod = true;
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: _"values are included in 2 or more array"_ - Your "solution" does not what your question says it should do. Your solution checks if every element of `tempDaysArray` is in `xmasPhase3` and if any of the elements in `tempDaysArray` is in `xmasPhase1` or `xmasPhase2` (hence the `if` should be `multiPhase && (Multiphase2 || multiPhase3)` - if we ignore the discrepancy between description and "solution")

Comment: @Andreas Thank u for pointing that out I noticed that I phrased everything very poorly with the last few braincells i had on the friday.